# Need help removing ¶ symbol from text field

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to remove the new paragraph symbol from a text field so when i paste results from my query into google sheets, it doesnt break the results up into multiple rows. I tried a few different approaches, mainly with the replace function, but am getting a "Cannot convert string from binary to utf8mb4" error. Has anyone experience this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the attempted `... REPLACE(...)...` query.

Comment: I dont have create table permissions but here is the logic im using. I believe its just a mysql specific issue though, because it runs on a db-fiddle

select replace('testtext¶testtext',char(182), ' ')

Answer (score 0):

The "pilcrow sign" is the two-byte hex `C2B6` in utf8.

In any of the following `CHARACTER SETs`, it is one-byte `B6`: cp1250, cp1251, cp1256, cp1257, dec8, geostd8, hebrew, latin1, latin5, latin7.

That is, your example code was attempting to *keep* the paragraph symbol, but change the encoding.  And that failed change was causing the problem.

Which do you want?  "remove"?  or fix the "encoding"?

Plan A:

The proper way to change a charset is via one of several tools, but not `REPLACE()`.

Perhaps the best approach is to establish `utf8mb4` as the `CHARACTER SET` throughout your MySQL connections and tables.  Then there would be no need to "replace" anything.  And that way, other non-ascii characters will not be any problem.

After connecting, do `SET NAMES utf8mb4`.  (There are other, better, ways to achieve this.)  When declaring `DATABASEs` and `TABLEs`, include `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

Meanwhile, the paragraph symbol will remain intact.

Plan B:

If you *really* want to remove that character, then do use `REPLACE`, but replace it with the empty string `''`.  (Or maybe a newline, `'\n'` or `'<BR>'` if the target it HTML.)

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply!

For Plan A, i checked the column configuration and the charset is already set to utf8mb4 and the collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci. I also dont have administrative permissions so cant alter these things myself but can make a suggestion to change them if necessary.

For Plan B, I tried both '' and '\n' but get the same error i listed above when running.

Comment: Don't replace with the latin1 equivalent, do what the question mentions and get rid of the Pilcrow completely.  If you are going through HTML, use `"<be>"`?